# How to format the name of inputs which belong in group

Tags: php, html-input

Sorry about that title if it's confusing, did my best to describe my question.

So I have a few inputs, in a form, which I want to 'group' together as they are part of the same entity.

I know to use brackets so that they are put into one array (by PHP), when using checkboxes for example, but my situation is a little different.

I have 3 inputs for a `person` and, in the form, there can be multiple `people`.

This is what it would look like if I were to only have one person in the form:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name"/>
<input type="text" name="last_name"/>
<input type="text" name="email"/>
```

But, I need to allow for multiple `people` and I would like them all to come through in one array in PHP, like this:

```
// print_r($_POST['people']);
array(
   [0] => array(
        'first_name'=>'john'
        'last_name' => 'smith'
        'email'=>'john.smith@example.com'
      )
   [1] => array(
        'first_name'=>'john2'
        'last_name' => 'smith2'
        'email'=>'john.smith@example.com2'
      )
 )
```

I have tried (1):

```
<input type="text" name="people[][first_name]"/>
<input type="text" name="people[][last_name]"/>
<input type="text" name="people[][email]"/>
```

and I have tried (2):

```
 <input type="text" name="people[first_name][]"/>
 <input type="text" name="people[last_name][]"/>
 <input type="text" name="people[email][]"/>
```

and I have tried (3):

```
 <input type="text" name="people[][first_name][]"/>
 <input type="text" name="people[][last_name][]"/>
 <input type="text" name="people[][email][]"/>
```

None of the above are coming through in the structure I mentioned further above.

How do I make `$_POST['people']` look like the array I showed above?

EDIT:

Here is what (1) produces:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => john
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => smith
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [email] => john.smith@example.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => john2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [last_name] => smith2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [email] => john.smith@example.com2
    )

)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with variant number 1?

Comment: @u_mulder I've updated my question to show what variant 1 produces ( `print_r`-ing `$_POST['people']` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **explicitly** set index to group items. In your case it will be:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="people[0][first_name]"/>
    <input type="text" name="people[0][last_name]"/>
    <input type="text" name="people[0][email]"/>
    <hr />

    <input type="text" name="people[1][first_name]"/>
    <input type="text" name="people[1][last_name]"/>
    <input type="text" name="people[1][email]"/>
    <hr />

    <input type="text" name="people[2][first_name]"/>
    <input type="text" name="people[2][last_name]"/>
    <input type="text" name="people[2][email]"/>
    <hr />

    <input type="submit" name="" value="" />
</form>
```

And in case of javascript adding new field, their names also should be with explicit indexes:

```
name="people[4][email]"
name="people[5][email]"
<!-- etc -->
```